# How to make dynamic checkbox input from JSON formed database

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, nested-forms

can anyone help me how to make dynamic checkbox?

so, i have JSON data like this

```
 [ {
  "categoryName" : "Category 1",
  "items" : [ {
    "value" : "value1",
    "label" : "label1"
  }, {
    "value" : "value2",
    "label" : "label2"
  } ]
}, {
  "categoryName" : "Category 2",
  "items" : [ {
    "value" : "value3",
    "label" : "label3"
  } ]
} ]
```

as i know that checkbox inputs are require property like value and label, so all i need to do is fill that property with data from that JSON, the problem is how to make this checkbox is auto-generate based on data from that JSON.

the result should be like
[THIS PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3hFj.png)

PS: sorry for my bad english

Comment: Is this straight javascript or are you using a library/framework like React or Angular?

Comment: @MattE with the `reactjs` tag I think he's talking about React FrameWork. For the question: First, you need to understand that we'll not code anything for you and for free, but we can help with your code. Edit and put you tests, and what wrong with thems ? If you didn't start to code, i can suggest you to start with the basic Formik example for checkbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/pjqp3xxq7q?from-embed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  const array = [ {
  "categoryName" : "Category 1",
  "items" : [ {
    "value" : "value1",
    "label" : "label1"
  }, {
    "value" : "value2",
    "label" : "label2"
  } ]
}, {
  "categoryName" : "Category 2",
  "items" : [ {
    "value" : "value3",
    "label" : "label3"
  } ]
} ]

let category = "";
let checkboxes = "";

array.forEach(el => {
category += `<h3>${el.categoryName}</h3>
`;
 if (el.items.length > 0) {
 el.items.forEach(v => {
 checkboxes += `<input type ="checkbox" value="${v.value}"> <label for 
 ="${v.value}">${v.label}</label>`;
  });
 } else {
checkboxes = ``;
}
});
```

Not tested but i hope it gives you a clue to solve your problem.